# Custom MKAnnotation click range

Tags: ios, mkannotation

I'm busy with an iPhone application and for that I'm using a custom MKAnnotation. But I have to press really hard to let it call the method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
```

Sometimes it doesn't call it at all.

Does anyone know how I can increase the click range of my MKAnnotation?

Comment: Oops, solved it! The thing I did wrong was not calling [mapView deselect annotation..... in the didSelectAnnotationView method.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, solved it! The thing I did wrong was not calling [mapView deselect annotation..... in the didSelectAnnotationView method.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. To finish the process, please click the tick on the left to accept this answer - That way, others don't try to solve your problem before realising it's already been solved. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, I will do, as soon as I'm able to. (that's tomorrow)